# Console log is running after setInterval

Tags: angular, settimeout, setinterval

I have an array of object, I should set isChecked property to true to first tree elements of array. After index of array is 3, I should redirect to another page, but console log is still run

```
public sendApplication(): void {
    if (this.formService.isFormValid(this.formGroup)) {
        this.dialogProcessing
            = this.dialog.open(FoDialogBankVerificationComponent, {
            width: '500px',
            disableClose: true,
            data: this.checkBoxValues,
        });
        this.submit()
            .pipe(
                take(1))
            .subscribe(res => {
                if (res.id === 1700) {
                    this.checkBoxValues.forEach((checkbox, index) => {
                        setInterval(() => {
                            checkbox.isChecked = true;
                            if (index === this.checkBoxValues.length - 1) {
                                this.status = res.id;
                                this.dialogProcessing.close();
                            }
                        }, index * 1000);
                    });
                } else {
                    this.checkBoxValues.forEach((checkbox, index) => {
                        setInterval(() => {
                            console.log(index)
                            if (index !== 3) {
                                checkbox.isChecked = true;
                            } else {
                                this.dialogProcessing.close();
                                this.navigationService.navigateToDeniedPage();
                            }
                        }, index * 1000);
                    });
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are not clearing the interval, to do that,

First declare a variable like,

```
interval:any;
```

Then assign setInterval like this and use the same to perform clearInterval as well,

```
this.interval = setInterval(() => {
   checkbox.isChecked = true;
   if (index === this.checkBoxValues.length - 1) {
       this.status = res.id;
       clearInterval(this.interval); 
       this.dialogProcessing.close();
   }
 }, index * 1000);
```

> Likewise you have to clear your another intervals as well when you
>   don't need them anymore.

Let me know if this does not solve your problem

Comment: Unfortunately no, and I think that you make a mistake:
`this.interval.clearInterval();`
It's should be `clearInterval(this.interval);`

Comment: yes @prolina my mistake, but this should work, as you have some unsubscribed sort of thing going on here. that's why your console.log() is getting executed again and again.

Comment: @prolina have you tried doing clearInterval() when you are about to leave the page?

Comment: I try to use clearInterval in the OnDestroy hook, but console.log  is getting executed again and again

Comment: @prolina Can you create stackblitz for this, can you kinda reproduce this in minimal way, I can help that way.